# Select data from anonymous collection

Tags: c#, linq

How can I get output like first query from second query.

Query 1:

```
var students = context.Students.Select(o => new
        {
            id = o.StdId,
            name = o.Name
        });
```

Query 2:

```
var students = context.Database.SqlQuery<object/??>("SELECT  StdId id, Name name FROM Students");
```

Comment: What about checking the type and casting into `Student` object? `(obj as Student).StdId`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26749429/anonymous-type-result-from-sql-query-execution-entity-framework

Comment: Use SqlDataReader - here is an example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20101807/2029818

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `context.Database.SqlQuery` with an anonymous type. You need to define you Student class (with Id, Name) and use it.

Answer (score 0):

See code below

```css
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication21
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string connStr = "Enter your connection string here";
            string SQL = "SELECT  StdId id, Name name FROM Students";

            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(SQL, connStr);

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(dt);

            var student = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .Select(x => new { id = x.Field<int>("id"), name = x.Field<string>("name") }).ToList();

        }
    }
}
```