# Cannot insert numeric value into my SQL table

Tags: sql, database, insert

I currently have 2 tables in my database, 1 with an autonumeric value called ZoekcriteriaID which is the primary key off the table Zoekcriteria.

I want to add the primary key (ZoekcriteriaID) to my other table called Resultaten as a forgeign key but I keep getting the same error.

It seems like `cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ZoekcriteriaID",Convert.ToInt32(sqlZoekcriteriaID));` keeps trying to add the entire query as a numeric value and I can't seem to figure out why.

Could anyone help me?

```
namespace Proftaak
{
class Mysearch

{
    public  string zoekterm = "";
    int resultaat = 1;
    public string Zoekterm
    {
        get
        {
            return zoekterm;
        }
        set
        {
            zoekterm = value;
        }
    }

    public void InsertZoekcriteria()
    {
        OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
        connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\martijn\Dropbox\Proftaak Periode 2 Identity\Database11.accdb;
        Persist Security Info=False;";
        connection.Open();
        string sqlstring = "INSERT INTO Zoekcriteria (ZoekCriteria) values ('" + Zoekterm + "')";

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sqlstring, connection);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
    }
    public void searchding()
    {


        const string apiKey = "AIzaSyDIm9ZOWD8Zd-2tHy5r3c0R-_XjdEFaXGE";
        const string searchEngineId = "003470263288780838160:ty47piyybua";
        string query = zoekterm;
        CustomsearchService customSearchService = new CustomsearchService(new Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.Initializer() { ApiKey = apiKey });
        Google.Apis.Customsearch.v1.CseResource.ListRequest listRequest = customSearchService.Cse.List(query);
        listRequest.Cx = searchEngineId;
        Search search = listRequest.Execute();
        OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
        connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\martijn\Dropbox\Proftaak Periode 2 Identity\Database11.accdb;
        Persist Security Info=False;";
        connection.Open();
        string sqlZoekcriteriaID = "SELECT ZoekcriteriaID from Zoekcriteria where Zoekcriteria='" + query + "'";
        OleDbCommand cmdZoekcriteria = new OleDbCommand(sqlZoekcriteriaID, connection);
        cmdZoekcriteria.ExecuteNonQuery();

          foreach (var item in search.Items)
        {


            string sqlstring1 = @"INSERT INTO Resultaat (ResultatenID,ZoekcriteriaID, Titel, Webadress) VALUES (@ResultatenID,@ZoekcriteriaID, @Titel, @Webadress)";

          OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand(sqlstring1, connection);
          cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ResultatenID", resultaat);
          cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ZoekcriteriaID",Convert.ToInt32(sqlZoekcriteriaID));
          cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Titel", item.Title);
          cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Webadress", item.Link);
          //    string sqlstring2= "INSERT INTO Resultaat(Titel) values ('"+item.Title+"')";
     //     OleDbCommand cmd2 = new OleDbCommand(sqlstring2, connection);
          resultaat++;
          cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }


        connection.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because it does:

```
  string sqlZoekcriteriaID = "SELECT ZoekcriteriaID from Zoekcriteria where Zoekcriteria='" + query + "'";
  cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ZoekcriteriaID",Convert.ToInt32(sqlZoekcriteriaID));
```

What you want is use the result of the query. What you should do is described in the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20101705/how-to-save-select-sql-query-results-in-an-array-in-c-sharp-asp-net) question.

You should also rethink the naming of your variables; `query`is not a query, for example, just a search condition.

Comment: I've figured it out myself by testing some things
I removed the cmdZoekcriteria.ExecuteNonQuery(); by string zoekwaardecriteria = cmdZoekcriteria.ExecuteScalar().ToString(); which worked.

Answer (score 0):

Before close the connection, recover the identity number, like this:

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sqlstring, connection);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


   cmd.CommandText = "SELECT @@IDENTITY";
   integer ZoekcriteriaID = cmd.ExecuteScalar()

  connection.Close();
```

Than you can use the ZoekcriteriaID on the other insert.

Refer to this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2009/12/02/getting-autonumber-from-access-via-select-identity-needs-to-be-done-in-same-connection-as-the-insert.aspx)

Comment: I've used cmdZoekcriteria.ExecuteScalar().ToString(); instead of the ExecuteNonQuery(); which also solved the problem!

Thanks for the help! I can use ur method aswell