# How do I put values from a column of a SQL table into an array in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, arrays

I want to put the values of a column of a SQL table into an array.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID FROM tblTray2");
string[] array = new string[ID];
```

This is what I have.

Anyone have tips?

Comment: first tip: _execute the command_.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save SELECT sql query results in an array in C# Asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20101705/how-to-save-select-sql-query-results-in-an-array-in-c-sharp-asp-net)

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
int i = 0;
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID FROM tblTray2");
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
string[] arrayID = new string[ID];

while(reader.Read() == true)
{
    arrayID[i] = reader["ID"].ToString();
    i++;
}
```